# Why does Cucumber only read what's in parentheses in an example table?

Tags: automation, tdd, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm having difficulties with parentheses in a cucumber examples table. I've included an example table to highlight the issue.

```
Examples:

Category         |Code Type  |Routes                            |
Child (Under 6)  |CHI        |GA1, GA2, DU1, CO3                |
Student          |STU        |GA1, GA2, DU1, CO3, SL4, EN3, LI5 |
Standard         |STA        |AA1                               |
```

When the examples table is read in it is only picking up the text (Under 6) - not Child (Under 6).

I have tried escaping the parentheses but it didn't work. I can't change the category to not include parentheses.

I've searched and searched and haven't been able to find anything that even references this issue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Cucumber are you using? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Hi - cucumber version 1.1.2

Comment: Is upgrading an option? I'm running version 2.0.2, and like I said, I can't reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option at the moment. Thanks for checking!

Comment: As a workaround until you can upgrade, you could replace the () in the table with a placeholder, like XXX and then do a replace on that field in your step definition.